# Computing the entanglement entropy in non-abelian lattice gauge theory using superselection sectors

Tags: quantum-information, entropy, holographic-principle, lattice-gauge-theory

I have been trying to understand how the entanglement entropy of a non-abelian lattice gauge theory. This was discussed in the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07455, section 2.2.

First why is the choice of superselection sectors, $k_i = (J_{T,in,i})^2 = (J_{T,out,i})^2$,  for all boundary vertices $V_i$. Then if we consider the above superselection sectors then, I believe that for the angular momentum $j_i$ corresponding to $J_{T,in,i}$, we would have $k_i = j_i(j_i+1)$, and the irreducible representation of $J_{T,in,i}$ would be $2j_i+1$ dimensional. But how would this lead to the following decomposition of the Hilbert space
$\mathcal{H}^k_{in} = \mathcal{H}^1\otimes\mathcal{H}^2\otimes\cdots\otimes\mathcal{H}^i\otimes\cdots\otimes\mathcal{H}^n\otimes\hat{\mathcal{H}}^k_{in}$, where $\mathcal{H}^i$ is a $2j_i+1$ dimensional Hilbert space.

Also I didn't understand how they are generalizing this result, the one obtained using SU(2) to a general non-abelian gauge theory, eqn (2.30) in the above paper.